# Getting started with Meteor: Show/Hide Templates on click

Tags: javascript, meteor

I have two template forms in a page one for "Log In" and another "Sign Up". Understood to use `Accounts` package from documentation. But could not figure out how to toggle between these two forms when user clicks on "Log In" link or "Sign Up" link?

Code:

```
<body>
<div class="blog-masthead">
      <div class="container">
        <nav class="blog-nav">
          <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">Home</a>
          <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Login</a>
          <a class="blog-nav-item active" href="#">Sign Up</a>
          <a class="blog-nav-item" href="#">About</a>
        </nav>
      </div>
    </div>
    {{> signInForm}}
</body>
<template name="signInForm">
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" role="form" id="signInForm">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please Log in</h2>
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="" id="login-email">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" id="login-password">
        <div class="row">
           <label class="remember-me">
                <input type="checkbox" name="remember-me" value="remember-me" id="remember-me" > Remember me
           </label> 
           <a href="#" class="pull-right">Forgot Password</a>
        </div>
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Log in</button>
        <p class="text-left">First time user?  <a href="#">Register</a></p>
      </form>

    </div>
</template>

<template name="signUpForm">
    <div class="container">
      <form class="form-signin" role="form" id="signUpForm">
        <h2 class="form-signin-heading">Please sign up</h2>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" placeholder="Name" required="" autofocus="" id="signup-name">
        <input type="email" class="form-control" placeholder="Email address" required="" autofocus="" id="signup-email">
        <input type="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password" required="" id="signup-password">
        <button class="btn btn-lg btn-primary btn-block" type="submit">Sign Up</button>
        <p class="text-left">Already have account?  <a href="#">Login</a></p>
      </form>

    </div>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, if you want to do it "The Meteor Way" there are two basic options and you need to decide which suits your need best:

a. you can inject the template you want to use to a placeholder using UI.insert and UI.render (or UI.renderWithData if you need data to be rendered, example:

```
UI.insert(UI.render(Template.name), document.body)
UI.insert(UI.renderWithData(Template.foo, {bar: "baz"}), document.body)
```

b: you can use Session based conditions in your template and order it to appear only when a certain Session is set, example:

```
 <template name="signInForm">
    <div class="signUp"> click me to make the sign up form appear</div>
    <div class="container">
    {{#with userPressedSignUp}}
      <form class="form-signin" role="form" id="signUpForm">
       .. form elements..
      </form>
    {{/with}
 </template>

 Template.signInForm.userPressedSignUp = ->
   return Session.get 'signUp-visible"

 Template.signInForm.events
    'click .signUp': (event) ->
       Session.set 'signUp-visible', true

 Session.set 'signUp_visible', false

  # The template will not show the contents of the "with" as long as the session
  # variable is 'false', change it by clicking on "signUp" div when you want the form to appear
```

Comment: Can you please explain second option more?
How would I set these session values when user will click on `Log In` or `Sign Up` links?